# Counting unique numbers from random sampling

Tags: probability

I pick $N$ numbers randomly from the set $\{1,.., N\}$ (with replacement), then what is the probability that exactly $k$ distinct numbers are chosen?

I.e. probability that $1$ distinct number is chosen would be $\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N-1}$. The probability that $N$ distinct numbers are chosen would be $\frac{N!}{N^N}$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The probability that there is 1 distinct number chosen is ${N \choose 1} (1/N)^{N-1}$, since there are $N$ numbers that could be chosen.  This gives a hint on how to work out other values.

Comment: Matthew, you are saying that when $N=2$, the probability of selecting 1 distinct number is $2*\frac{1}{2} = 1$?

Comment: Oops.  Yes, it should be ${N \choose 1}(1/N)^N$.  Thanks.  This gives a form that can be extended, using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Here's an example of a way to do it directly: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550675/the-number-of-rolls-of-6-dice-with-exactly-4-distinct-values

Comment: This answer also gives some ideas: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89794/count-the-number-of-ways-of-four-distinct-numbers-showing-up-when-six-dice-are-r

Comment: I've discovered a complete formula in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408983/expected-number-of-repeats-in-random-strings-from-different-sized-alphabets?rq=1